# Why does cypher query to count number of nodes that has relation r runs extremely slowly? (>10 mins)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I built a database in neo4j using stackoverflow's data dump. I can't help but notice that queries run extremely slowly.

1. Is there something in the config that i am missing?
2. Indexes have been built on the ID of each node.
3. The database would often crash when i run this query.

This is the query I am trying to run as well as related screenshots.

`match (a:Posts)-[r:HAS_TAG]->(t:Tag {TagId:"java"}) return count(a.Title)`

Using `explain`, it seems like a query that should execute quickly.

[image]

Comment: Well, this should be okay with any configs, but: how much memory does Neo4j have? Also, you can probably rephrase the query: what is the goal of counting a.Title values? Would `count(a)` work instead?

Comment: As Gabor says, if you only need the node count, get that instead, as you'll save on not having to do property access for the node. Also, use PROFILE instead of EXPLAIN if you want to see more performance info, such as db hits and the number of rows operated on as the query progresses.

Comment: Additionally, if counting the relationships is enough, you can do that without having to do the expansions at all: `(t:Tag {TagId:"java"}) RETURN size((t)<-[:HAS_TAG]-()) as javaPostsCount`

Comment: @GaborSzarnyas i've set it up with 32gb ram and a 200gb ssd. And you're right, i didn't have to count the a.Title values